# When deleting row using trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt strange missing other rows issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to delete row from UITableView by using trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt function.

The row gets deleted and disappears. This part is ok.

But next rows that are coming to the screen or when I swipe down the same amount as the rows been deleted are not even loaded on the tableView.

![img1]https://poirot.deus4.com/photo_2019-06-12_16-44-01.jpg

![img2]https://poirot.deus4.com/photo_2019-06-12_16-43-56.jpg

![img3]https://poirot.deus4.com/photo_2019-06-12_16-43-49.jpg

![img4]https://poirot.deus4.com/photo_2019-06-12_16-43-38.jpg

[video]https://poirot.deus4.com/RPReplay_Final1560345600.mp4

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filteredProducts.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: .cellID, for: indexPath) as! ProductTableCell

        cell.backgroundColor = .red
        return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

        let hide = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Hide") { action, view, completion in

            self.filteredProducts.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)

            completion(true)
        }

        hide.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "hdie_product")
        hide.backgroundColor = .midGrey

        let conf = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [hide])
        return conf
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I did not call super.prepareForReuse() inside TablewViewCell

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse() // this was missing

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you showed obviously works, thus the problem is elsewhere.
Without other code I suspect that the problem is because table view cells are re-used: When you scroll your table view, some cells are scrolled out of view and can be reused. Cells that are scrolled in are either re-used cells or new cells.
In any case, the table view datasource function `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` must be used to configure the displayed cells.
It seems too me that you do not configure the cells in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`.
If so, re-used cells look as the were when they have been scrolled out, but new cells are simply blank.
So I suggest to check if you really configure all the cells in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added two functions to my question. Right now I'm just dequeueing reusable cell as usually. And setting red background for this example. The interesting thing is that I created another project with simple UITableViewController and there everything works just fine. But in this project I tried to create Controller programmatically and now I am doing this in storyboard. Sadly the result is the same.

Comment: I assume you did register the cell identifier with your tableView, right?

Comment: also tableViewController in embedded in NavigationController. But I don't know how this can be related

Comment: No I'm trying to try different things. Currently I kinda got situation: if I use my ProductTableViewCell the issue will appeat. But if I remove Custom class from the cell it works fine. Maybe you know how this can be related?

Comment: Maybe you could show the actual implementation of `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` with your custom class? The one you show in your question is just a stub implementation that does not create the pictures that you showed, but sets only the cell background.

Comment: I found an issue!
```
override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        
 }
```
I did not call super.prepareForReuse() in cell

oh god.. it took a while))

anyway thank your for support!

Comment: Great! Maybe you could write an answer and accept it so that the question is closed. And it could help others!